# Why do I get extra element when getting every other element in a list?

Tags: list, haskell

I'm new to haskell and I dont know why I'm getting an extra element in a list.

Here's my code:

```
module Test where

    deal list = hand1
        where list' = fst(splitAt 4 list)
              hand1 = [snd list' | list'<- (zip [0..] list), even (fst list')]
```

If I were to put in:

```
Test.deal [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

It splits the list to create to create a tuple of two lists one with length of 4: `([1,2,3,4],[5,6])`

When I try to get every other element of the first list in the tuple, I get: `[1,3,5]` instead of `[1,3]`

Anyone know why it adds the 5 even though it isn't in the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are defining two different `list'`. The one inside the list comprehension `list'<- (zip [0..] list)` shadows the previous one. Shadowing means you have two equal names in scope but the one lexically closer is the only one visible. You want something like:

```
module Test where
    deal list = hand1
        where list0 = fst (splitAt 4 list)
              hand1 = [snd list1 | list1 <- (zip [0..] list0), even (fst list1)]
```

With these changes, I can do

```
λ> deal [1,2,3,4,5,6]
[1,3]
```

Comment: Good point about the shadowing. However, in this case it does work even with shadowing.

Comment: I think it's a mixture of the two, I mean shadowing and referring to the wrong variable. Specially shadowing, it often bit beginers.